# Django | JS variable inside dynamic URL

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I'm trying to pass a javascript variable inside a dynamic url using Django. I have the following path

```
path('task-update/<str:pk>/', updateTask, name='task-update'),
```

I'm able to retrieve the "Task" fields I created (id, title, description, ...) depending on what task I select inside the HTML (this is done using AJAX and the Django-REST Framework). However, I'm having some trouble on rendering javascript values inside dynamic urls

```
var url = `{% url 'task-update' pk=${activeItem.id} %}`
```

The **${activeItem.id}** is where I'm having some trouble, I tried assigning it to a variable and passing that into the URL but it doesn't work.

A workaround I've been using is

```
var url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/task-update/${activeItem.id}/`
```

however I'd like to use django's template tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for quite a bit this was the best neat-looking solution I found (also the only one): [django-js-urls](https://pypi.org/project/django-js-urls).

Just **pip install django-js-urls** and add **'js_urls'** to your **INSTALLED APPS**.

Afterwards add simply add **JS_URLS** to your **settings.py** file and put the names of the paths you'd like to use. In my case I only added *task-update*, it looks something like this

```
JS_URLS = (
    'task-update',
)
```

Then, all you need to do is add the following in the URLs root module

```
from js_urls.views import JsUrlsView

urlpatterns = [
    # other urls
    url(r'^js-urls/$', JsUrlsView.as_view(), name='js_urls'),
]
```

And include the following js in the template

```
<script src="{% url 'js_urls' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

URLs can be used using the **window.reverse** function

```
var url = window.reverse('task-update', { pk: activeItem.id });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick that might work under most circumstances:

```
var url = "{% url 'task-update' pk=12345 %}".replace(/12345/, ${activeItem.id});
```

It's clean, and it doesn't break DRY principle.

Comment: Thanks, binpy. This solution doesn't seem to work, it seems it interferes with my javascript. I'm using Django REST Framework to update some values and doesn't seem to be working. I found a solution using django-js-urls (posted it below)